# how to solve in conflict css?

Tags: html, css

I have a problem in my webpage designing in css. I have this code of structure.

```
<div id="tabs">
   <ul>
      <li><a href="menu link"></a></li>
      ... other menu ...
   </ul>
   <div id="content">
       ... some codes ...
      <section class="slider">
        <div class="flexslider">
        <ul class="slides">
        <li>
            <img src="image/1.jpg" />
        </li>
                 ... other image ...
            </ul>
        </div>
      </slider>
   </div>

</div>
```

in #tabs it use the css of `#tab ul{}` for the design of the navigation bar menu for the `ul` and `li`.

when I apply the `flexslider` in my page, the flexslider's `ul` and `li` were also infected with the css design of `#tab ul` and `#tab li`.

is there any way that the flexslider's `ul` and `li` will not be infected by `#tab ul` and `#tab li`?

by the way, I cannot change the structure of the page because it will affect the other pages. I can only edit in the `content` div.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can have separate rules for

```
#tabs > ul
```

and

```
.flexslider > ul
```

Those rules won't propagate to `ul` deeper in the tree.

Answer (score -1):

add .flexsider ul and .flexsider ul li with !important at end.